# Best way to get rid of font tags?

Tags: html, css, fonts, tags

I have been working on a XSLT file here. I had been writing CSS for elements contained in the XSLT files. I need to get rid of font tags due to convention issues, is there any tag that i could use to get rid of this font tags where i can still retain the CSS classes for my specific elements contained in the font tags.

```
        <div class="TitleStyle">
          <font class="WhiteHeader">
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="title" />
          </font>
          <font class="ProviderStyle">
            @ <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="job_board_provider"/>
          </font>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<span>` (i.e. inline duct tape for HTML) should work:

```
<div class="TitleStyle">
  <span class="WhiteHeader">
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="title" />
  </span>
  <span class="ProviderStyle">
    @ <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="job_board_provider"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there many ways to get rid of `font` tag like give `span` instead of `font` tag & write your css on it.

```
 <span class="WhiteHeader">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="title" />
      </span>
```

css:

```
span{
 font-family:abc;
}
```